# como quitar el valor por default del select2

Tags: javascript

al usar select2 en js se me pone un valor de default que es este

```
<option value="" selected>---------</option>
```

lo que quiero es saber como quitarlo en value me da la posicion 0
aqui esta como esta el select2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', {
        noResults: function () {
            return 'No se encontraron resultados';
        }
    });




    // Crear los botones de radio
    var radioButtonContainer = $('<div>'); // Crear un contenedor para los botones de radio
    $('select[name="convocatoria"] option').each(function () {
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(optionValues);
        var optionText = $(this).text();
        optionValues.push(optionValue);
        optionTexts.push(optionText);
        var radioButton = $('<br>' + '<input type="radio" name="convocatoria" value="' + optionValue + '">');
        var label = $('<label>').text(optionText);


        // Manejar el cambio de selección en los botones de radio
        radioButton.on('change', function () {
            // Obtener el valor seleccionado
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            var selectedOptionText = $(this).text();
            $('#elementos-encuesta').show();

            if (optionText == 'HERMANOS') {
                hermanoField.show();
                $('#id_hermano').prop('required', true)
            } else {
                hermanoField.hide();
                $('#id_hermano').prop('required', false)
            }

            // Hacer algo con el valor seleccionado
            // console.log(selectedValue);
        });

        // Agregar los botones de radio y etiquetas al contenedor
        radioButtonContainer.append(radioButton, label);
    });

    // Reemplazar el campo de selección original con el contenedor de botones de radio
    $('select[name="convocatoria"]').replaceWith(radioButtonContainer);
```

en la primer parte donde esta el console.log(optionValues); me los imprime del la posicion 0 no me da valor aparece vacio que es el que quiero eliminar

Comment: puedes poner el Javascript con el que configuras el select2?

Comment: listo ya lo agrege